# !. Operator in Dart

Tags: dart

My primary language is C#, but I'm working on a flutter project in Dart.

Whilst trying to run an `myObject.iterableProp.all()` I've received this error:

> The method 'any' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver
> can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding
> a null check to the target ('!').

Now, I know why this is, because items in `iterableProp` could be `null`. However, this clause has me intrigued:

> or adding a null check to the target ('!')

So coming from C#, I'd always assumed that doing `myObject.iterableProp!.all()` was just a null error suppressor, rather than an actual null check.

So I was thinking of doing something like `myObject.iterableProp?.all() ?? false`.

Is what this warning is suggesting correct? That the `!.` operator actually inserts a null check and, thus, I can just throw that in and be done with it? One would assume that that null check would return false if it's null rather than throwing an exception, otherwise what would be the point?

Comment: [see null assertion operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators)

Comment: @mmcdon20 - So it isn't really a null check, it has the same effect as a supression would, we get a runtime null ref exception... That's one heavily misleading warning

Comment: It *is* a runtime `null` check in the sense that it checks if the value is `null`, and if it is, it throws an exception.  If you want graceful failure, you should use `?.`.  But also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47185

Comment: @jamesdlin - but if you don't do the check, you get the same exception no?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater No.  If you don't do the check, your code won't compile.  With `!`, you'll get a `TypeError` on failure.  Before null-safety, you would get a `NoSuchMethodError` when calling a method on `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In null-safe Dart, you are not allowed to do `myObject.iterableProp.all()` when `iterableProp` might return `null`.

So, you need to handle that potential `null` in some way.

The two most common ways are `?.` and `!.`.

The `?.` *propagates* the `null`, so `myObject.iterableProp?.all()` omits calling `all` when the `iterableProp` is `null`. Instead the result of the entire expression becomes `null`, since it needs a value and `all` isn't called to produce one. That's why you need the `?? false`.
That's all as you'd expect coming from, e.g., C#.

The `!.` *checks* for `null` and *throws* if it sees a `null` value.
Then `myObject.iterableProp!.all()` will either call `all()` on a non-`null` value, or it will throw. It's basically equivalent to
`(myObject.iterableProp ?? throw TypeError("is null!")).add()`.
That is a valid approach too, but you should only use it when you know, for some reason that the compiler cannot see, that `iterableProp` will in fact not be `null`.

Both `?.` and `!.` *checks* for null. They do different things in case they *see* a `null`, both in order to make the type of the entire expression make sense even if you can't call `all()`.

The `!` is not a "check" in the sense that it evaluates to a boolean. That wouldn't make sense in most expressions, where you expect a different type of expression.
That's why the `!` is also sometimes called a "null assertion", because its behavior is to throw if the check fails, like an assertion (but it works even if actual assertions are disabled, "assertion" already means something else, so that's why it's not the official name of the null-check operator).